# wordpress: Trigger hook on specific post id

Tags: wordpress

on my wordpress page I have a gallery which displays featured images. 
I would like to add HTML to a specific item, using the wordpress functions file.

If I run the following code:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'add_featured_image_html', 10, 1 );
function add_featured_image_html( $html ) {
    return $html .= '<p>'.get_the_ID().' is the ID</p>';
}
```

My frontend does display the post ID's underneath my thumbnails. In this case, I would like to target Post_ID 19 (btw this is a custom post type).

If I extend my code to:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
if ($id == 19) {
    add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'add_featured_image_html', 10, 1 );
    function add_featured_image_html( $html ) {
        return $html .= '<p>'.get_the_ID().' is the ID</p>';
    }
}
```

Nothing is displayed.

Is there someone that could help me out? thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of this filter is the post id.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/

This isn't tested yet, because I'm on my phone... But this should work.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'add_featured_image_html', 10, 2 ); 
    function add_featured_image_html( $html , $id) {
         if ($id == 19){
            return $html .= '<p>'.get_the_ID().' is the ID</p>';}
         else {return $html} 
}
```